# Delete files automatically if certain actions are not taken

Tags: automation, files, delete

Is it possible to delete/wipe files on device **offline**, if on certain time, certain action is not performed?

For example, if my phone is stolen, I would like to have a chance to delete certain sensitive data from device. But regularly, I can "check-in" to prevent the deletion.

Comment: Why not Android Device Manager?

Comment: Because it requires internet connection.

Comment: Question asking specifically for app recommendation is off-topic. Instead, explain the problem in general; answers which recommend apps are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Automation App like Tasker, every day at midnight it sets a variable to true and if you perform the "action" it sets it back to false and if its midnight and the variable is still true, than delete the data or do whatever you like

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the Tasker steps though. Not everyone is an expert on using Tasker...

Comment: Sorry but I didn't use Tasker for Months so I cant remember all the things from this app, but you need a variable from the last tab, and a time event from the first tab, there you have to add an if statement to delete the data and else set the variable to true and also you need the "action" which sets the variable to false. And dont forget to set the Variable to false at the beginning